# MySQL - Passing a query condition to a view within a view

Tags: mysql, view

I have created a view which uses another view to retrieve it's data.

This second view queries a table with a timestamp, and I would like to add a `WHERE` condition to the query of the first view that effects this timestamp of the second view.

So my query might be (this obviously doesn't work, but it gets across what I am trying to do I hope:

```
SELECT * FROM `view_1` WHERE `view_2.timestamp` >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00'
```

Is there a way to modify a WHERE clause of a view used within a view?

EDIT: To make it a little clearer what I am doing.

I am using a sub query, which is why I am having to use a second view. You can't have sub queries in MySQL views, so the sub query is in a another view. The sub query view is the one I would like to be able to and a WHERE dynamic `WHERE` clause when querying the first view.

**view_1**

```
SELECT `Case ID`, `Creation Date`,
    CASE WHEN `each_amount` > 1 THEN "YES" ELSE "NO" end AS 'Opened',
FROM [view_2]
WHERE `Creation End` <= NOW()
AND `First` = 1
ORDER BY `Creation Date` DESC
```

**view_2**

```
SELECT T0.timestamp AS 'Creation End', COUNT(T0.ipaddress) AS each_amount, MIN(T0.first) AS 'First',
FROM `mappin` AS T0
WHERE T0.timestamp >= '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
GROUP BY code_2
```

My Query of view_1 is

```
SELECT * FROM view_1
```

This query gets me everything from the `mappin` table on or after `'2014-04-20 00:00:00'`, this date is what I would like to change in my query of view_1.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to join view_1 and view_2. Something like,

select * form view_1 join view_2 on
view_1.id=view2.id where view_2.timestamp` >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00';

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just revised my question to make it clearer what I am doing. I am using view_2 as a sub-query of view_1. I am not sure how joining them in the query would work like this?

Comment: If you can provide sample data from the two views and the desired output it would help.

Comment: I have added the queries as suggested. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try to use a table inlined function which will take the input as the date and will pass that to the view2. Something like,
Create function GetView2ByDate
@date datetime
AS
RETURNS TABLE
BEGIN
SELECT T0.timestamp AS 'Creation End', COUNT(T0.ipaddress) AS each_amount, MIN(T0.first) AS 'First',
FROM `mappin` AS T0
WHERE T0.timestamp >= @Date
GROUP BY code_2
END

Please use appropriate syntax, this was just to give you an idea.

Comment: How would I pass the `datetime` in the query of view_1, so it's passed to the inline function of view_2?

Comment: Have a look,
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/26/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-table-valued-functions-day-26-of-35/

I am not sure how this can be implemented in MySQL